# what kind of grease to use on front shocks

Tags: suspension

I have managed to release my shocks from the compressed position. The uppers look in very good nick. It has a little corrosion on the uppers.

I brought a tub of pure bike eco grease ages ago and never used it. Is it possible to use this on the uppers and lowers?

http://www.sjscycles.co.uk/pure-eco-range-bike-grease-100g-tub-prod29089/

Comment: Is yours air sprung?

Comment: Need more info what brand / model of fork is this? If it's a cheap bike / fork it's probably not worth your time and effort. Grease will do very little to help a suspension fork perform any better.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the fork was non-functional or stuck.  Simply greasing the uppers isn't going to resolve the problem - you likely need to rebuild the entire shock assembly, replacing seals, lubricating internal parts, etc.  Every fork is a bit different, so you'll need to find service instructions for the specific manufacturer/model you own.  Or, have the local bike shop do it - it shouldn't be more than a few hours labor.

Comment: If it is corroded, it may be so old that parts aren't readily available. I loved my 2001 SID fork, but I tried to get it rebuilt two years ago and no one could do it. It may be time for a new fork.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, you can not use all types of lubricants on suspensions of rear shocks. The reason is that these are subject to high, fast friction and a lot of heat, so you need lubricants that are developed to handle these conditions.

It doesn't make sense to advice you an anything in particular, just be careful to buy suspension-specific oil and grease.

On a side note, if you are saying the shock used to be stuck in a compressed position, and have some rust in the upper-seals... none of those are good signals. Make sure your suspension is on good working order, or at least that it has enough structural integrity to be safe to use (take it to a shop if you're not sure). If you have some money on the side I would recommend buying a new one, even if it's a really cheap one (1 year guarantee is mandatory so at least you will have that :-) ). If you ride mainly on road buy a rigid fork (they are super cheap, [used](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Steel-Mountain-Bike-Rigid-Fork-26-1-1-8-Cantilever-9mm-QR-/381258439371?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item58c4c61acb) or [new](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ELITE-Scandium-super-lite-TEC-MTB-Bike-Mountain-V-Brake-1-1-8-Rigid-Fork-26-/321748052560?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ae9adaa50), for example) and forget maintenance for ever.

Be safe and good luck.

Comment: *"The reason is that these are subject to high, fast friction and a lot of heat, so you need lubricants that are developed to handle these conditions"*   -- almost comical in the context of bicycles.  What technical lubricant (i.e. not bacon grease or corn oil) cannot handle the pressures or temperatures that occur in some bicycle fork?

Comment: Depends on your riding style and the type of oil. I've been advised more than once not to use all kinds. After all, some suspensions and shocks have specific-designed air chambers to make up for air expansion under heat. I know people that use normal oil and they are ok, so do as you feel like, but for $7 a spray can (http://www.ebay.com/itm/Finish-Line-Max-Suspension-Spray-12oz-Aerosol-/171747141129?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27fced6609) that will last for ever I don't think it's worth it.